# package.json run multiple commands in sequence with same configuration

Tags: angular, package.json, npm-scripts

I need to run these two commands before each deplay:

1. `ng build --prod  --configuration=qa.europe-west1`
2. `ng run gw-web-app:server --configuration=qa.europe-west1`

I want to write one commands that perform those tow commands in sequence but to also have an option to change the configuration for both of the commands. So if I change the configuration in that commands it will change to each of the commands that are performed.

Something like: `npm run run-both-commands --configuration=qa.some-configuration`

Is there a way to write a commands in the package.json that will allow to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a batch file like below:

```
echo Enter Configuration
set /p configString="Enter Commit label : "
ng build --prod  --configuration=%configString%
ng run gw-web-app:server --configuration=%configString%
```

Comment: I am looking for a package.json scripts command that can do it